# preg_match array

Tags: php

It says that it "expects parameter 1 to be string". So i guess you cant have an array in preg_match. But what should I use instead? Thanks

```
$config['forbidden_names'] = array('admin', 'moderator', 'hoster');


if (preg_match($config['forbidden_names'], $string)) echo "Forbidden name!";
```

edit: in_array maybe. lol. im stupid

Answer (score 1):

```
if (in_array($string, $config['forbidden_names']))
    echo "Forbidden name!";
```

Or if you must use regex:

```
if (preg_match('/^(?:admin|moderator|hoster)$/', $string))
    echo "Forbidden name!";
```

Comment: Your regular expression does match strings that either start with `admin`, have `moderator` at any position, or end with `hoster`.

Comment: @Gumbo Eh damn precedence. Fixed, but feel free to edit any time.

Answer (score 1):

Change your second line to:

```
if (in_array($string, $config['forbidden_names'])) echo "Forbidden name!";
```

preg_match uses a regular expression, you should stay away from it unless you really need to search through a regex string, because it is slow.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if (preg_match('/(admin|moderator|hoster)/i', $string)) echo "Forbidden name!";
```

btw i would rather add to your roles model/table a new column/settings var that manages stuff user is allowed to add. this looks insecure to me.

Comment: It's exactly what we don't want to do. This array is just an example.

Comment: a very bad example then, bacause i can imagen a form where user could edit his roles and by only editing the dom he could assign himself a admin role. so not sure what he ment